# Exercise 9.G in Bartle's "Elements of Integration"

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

The question goes as follows:

Let $A$ be a Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Then, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is an open set $G_\varepsilon \supseteq A$ such that
$$l^*(A) \leq l^*(G_\varepsilon) \leq l^*(A) + \varepsilon$$

Here, $l^*$ denotes the outer Lebesgue measure. I tried proving it like this:

Given $\varepsilon > 0 $, there is a sequence $(a_j, b_j]$ of half-open intervals such that $A \subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty (a_j, b_j]$ and $\sum_{j=1}^\infty l^*((a_j, b_j]) \leq l^*(A) + \varepsilon/2$ - by the definition of the outer measure. Let $G_\varepsilon = \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty (a_j, b_j) \cup \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty \left(b_j - \frac{\varepsilon}{2^{j+2}}, b_j + \frac{\varepsilon}{2^{j+2}} \right)$ - which is an open set. Then $A \subseteq G_\varepsilon$, and, therefore, $$l^*(A) \leq l^*(G_\varepsilon) \leq \sum_{j=1}^\infty l^*((a_j, b_j)) + \varepsilon \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{j+1}} = \sum_{j=1}^\infty l^*((a_j, b_j]) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \leq l^*(A) + \varepsilon$$

Is this proof right? I'm confused because I didn't use the fact that $A$ is Lebesgue measurable. Can anyone help me?